# How to escape semicolon in Java Scanner

Tags: java, escaping, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to take an input using `Scanner` class in Java.

My code is:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner( System.in);
String newline = scan.next();
```

My input is something like:

```
india gate;25;3
```

and I'm trying to replace the whole string above with a new string:

```
new delhi;23;2
```

using

```
 .replace(str1, str2)
```

The problem is it's only replacing the first word in the string and the output is something like:

```
india delhi;25;3
```

How can I take it as a whole string using `Scanner`?

Comment: use `;` as your delimiter.

Comment: please show all of your code.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next(java.lang.String)

see this.

Comment: guys white space is the problem here ,but using ; as a delimiter would split my string  wherever it finds a ; which i dont want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read up on how the `Scanner` class works. Basically by default, it uses whitespace as the delimiter for `next()`. This means that when you call `next()`, it reads until it finds whitespace, then it returns what it read. So when you call `next()` on `"india gate;25;3"`, it reads `"india"` and then hits a space. So it returns you `"india"`. If you want to read until a newline instead (which it looks like you do), you want to use `nextLine()`.

Comment: that is what i say in my answer but she didn't agree. :)

Comment: I think she took issue with your answer splitting the string on the semicolons.

Comment: yeah she has a issue with that whitespace.

Comment: yes! thankyou @Neatname nextline worked ,no while loops nothing

Answer (score 1):

Use `;` as delimiter like this

```
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    lineScanner = new Scanner(scanner.nextLine());
    lineScanner.useDelimiter(";");
    String article = lineScanner.next();
    // and so on...
}
```

Comment: thank you kishan but using ; as a delimeter would split up the string based on ; i do not want to split my string and rather retain it intact

Comment: approve my edit or else do by your self manually so that others don't get confuse. @NitikaJain

Comment: scan.usedelimeter is slowing down the whole process actually the program is not moving ahead only...

Answer (score 1):

use  `.replaceAll("india gate;25;3", "new delhi;23;2");`

**output**

```
new delhi;23;2
```

Comment: input comes dynamic u can't do this for all.

Comment: if input comes dynamic then also we can also regex but more specific